# Database design - normalisation query

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am a teacher and am querying a solution given by our examination board. The question is shown below and I'd like to ask for help in understanding why **my solution** would not be acceptable.

Here's the original question / scenario:

---

[image]

[image]

---

Here is my solution:

---

[image]

---

The Solution, given by our examining board, is shown below. As you'll see, they indicate the need for a 'AssignedSeat' entity. I understanding they are resolving a Many-to-Many relationship here, but I asking if my solution (in blue) would be equally valid by just using these 2 entities?

---

**Standard Mark Scheme**
[image]

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is not equally valid since it has redundancy that can be eliminated. Consider a customer who books 10 seats for a certain show. In your case you have 10 rows (each with 3 items, for a total of 30 items) to represent this fact. In the solution shown, instead, there are only 23 items to represent the same information (10 rows with 2 items, and a single row with 3 items). Since redundancy is bad in database design, the solution with three relations is better than the solution with only two relations.

From a formal point of view, we have that

```
ShowingId, SeatNumber -> CustomerId
```

but in the relation `BOOKING(CustomerId, ShowingId, SeatNumber)`, the pair `(ShowingId, SeatNumber)` is not a candidate key, so the relation is not in Boyce-Codd Normal Form (although it *is* in Third Normal Form).